# Book about a boy with telekinesis who escapes from a doctor and steals wallets using power to survive the streets

Tags: story-identification, novel, telekinesis

I am looking to reunite my friend to his childhood book. He would have read it in 2010. It's apparently a series. A boy has telekinesis powers. Dr. Browler (not sure if that's the correct name) is the antagonist.

The boy escapes the facility and a vivid scene my friend remembers is that the boy uses his powers to remove wallets from people's pockets. When he returns the wallets, the people then give him money as a thank you. The boy needs the money to survive the streets as the doctor searches for him.

Answer (score -1):

It's [*Hidden Talents*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23168828-hidden-talents) by David Lubar!

> When thirteen-year-old Martin Anderson arrives at the Edgeview Alternative School, it's the end of the road. Literally. He's been expelled from every other school. Edgeview is the last stop. A warehouse for the system's rejects.
>
> Martin fits right in.
>
> Everyone has given up on Martin. Even Martin. But at Edgeview Martin falls in with a group of five outsiders who make the other Edgeview rejects appear gifted by comparison. He makes a remarkable each of his friends possesses a remarkable talent. One is telekinetic. Another is empathic. Others have psychic abilities. Martin thinks these talents make them special. They think it makes them freaks.
>
> Martin has one shot to convince them otherwise.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] your answer to include quotes or a summary that demonstrate how this book matches the question?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this identifies the work? Other than one boy having telekinesis, nothing else seems to match...